# Does anyone know of a 'LINQ to XLSX' provider?

Tags: linq, xlsx

Does anyone know of a 'LINQ to XLSX' provider?

We're considering the purchase of a third party solution for reading xlsx files (GemBox, GrapeCity, SpreadsheetGear, etc.) OR doing something from scratch with LINQ. This is a common requirement for us so despite being a fairly big task, building our framework is not out of the question. Before we dig in too deeply, it would be great to see what others have done with LINQ and to gauge the level of complexity for doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a linq provider, but EPPlus is pretty fantastic...and it's free!

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using LinqToExcel and found to be a very good tool. You will need to have a JET or Ace DB provider installed on any server/machine you wish to use it on which you can find on the Microsoft website. you can read all about it on the project's Github page:

https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel